# SFTP not working on disk mount

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I run a  Google Cloud Instance on Ubuntu 18.4, I added a Google persistent disk as instructed on Google's docs and works as intended. I can create, delete and move files over SSH.

I moved a vhost over to the mount and adapted the users SFTP details to point to that vhost but it doesn't connect. I also have the correct permissions.

Does anyone know if I need to do something else to get SFTP to work.

I use the following in /etc/ssh/sshd_config to lock the user into that instance.

```
Match User username
ForceCommand internal-sftp
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChrootDirectory /mnt/disk1/username
PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was to do with the file permissions. Although the folders were 755 some of them just weren't responding with 755. So I ran a chmod on those files and all is now working as intended.